# Ajax post not working

Tags: html, ajax, csrf

I am trying to post a form via ajax. Its giving me "405 Method Not Allowed" error. The same html file works if i put the url in the action part of html form and submit it manually on a button click(so its not a csrf issue..rite?).

what could be the problem?

Comment: could you post the code?

Comment: Your website will add an CSRF hidden field to your forms so that they pass CSRF validation. When doing Ajax requests, they do not have these hidden fields, so fail. I simply looked for the hidden field and got it's value and added it to the list of values to send as a post.

Comment: @Engineer — The Same Origin Policy wouldn't cause a 405 error.

Comment: @Gavin — It won't unless it is set up to do so. CSRF should throw a 403 not a 405 anyway.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the underlying site. If it's setup to throw an 405, it will. Is your backend code PHP and are you using a third party framework such as CodeIgniter or DJango?

Comment: are you posting to your server? what code is used on the server side?

Comment: The calling script is pure html/js file on desktop, the called script is server running at some port. how to find that hidden field which contains CSRF token?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are using the same method for your ajax request. 
Maybe you are using "POST" method for you form and "GET" for your ajax request.

CSRF should throw a 403 and if the a method (POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,...) is not allowed you will see a 405 error message.

**Edit:** Try to submit your form with jquery:

```
// change the selector!
var data = $("form").serialize();
alert(data);

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/your-backend.php",
 data: data,
```

});

What does firebug says when you do this?

Comment: nopes, i cross checked that, they are same. As Gavin said the hidden field, if it exist in the form, is the cause. how to retrieve that hidden field?

Comment: I used the serialize method, alerted it, could not find any field that contains CSRF token. Same error persist in firebug "405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: and your form has a field with a csrf token?

Comment: nopes, could not find any field with csrf token, used form.serialize method to chk that.